# Handling UK Date/Time Format for Animation in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, animation, datetime

I am attempting to make a time animation in ArcGIS of measured field data across a continuous sequence of 1Hz spatial sampling.

My data are a series of XY points with assigned datetime, lat, long and a measurement which plots nicely in ArcMap (version 10.4.1). However, I have a time variable displayed in the format of "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss". This format does not allow for time animations to work, creating just 2 timestep keyframes. Although I have tried to re-work the date format to something ArcMap can handle, the **Convert Time Field** outputs YYYYMMDD000000 for all values with all time as zeroes. The issue is I need the data in seconds (1Hz) for a proper animation.

Can anyone recommend how to handle this date format **or** how to use the animation tool to get what I want (continuous track of collected 1Hz data)?

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/1179/)

Comment: And the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/time/supported-field-formats.htm) which asserts `hh` as 24-hour.

Comment: What have you tried to convert the data? In my experience, you need a text field conversion first so you don't lose anything. Also, you are using a geodatabase, not a shape file?